# converting EXCEL code to SAS

Tags: excel, count, sum, sas

I am fairly new to SAS. 
I designed an algorithm under excel and I am having a lot of trouble converting it to SAS

In Excel :

```
A B
-1 1
1 .
1 2
0 1
-1 .
-1 2
```

What it does from A to B is that it counts how many times you find the occurrence A in a row. For example (-1) is only here one time, so 1. Then 1, 1 are following each other so I have . (= not significant) followed by 2 (because you have two 1s).
And so on so on.
My working excel code for column B is :
for the first row :

```
IF (A1 = A2, NA(), 1)
```

for the rest of column B (row 10 for example):

```
IF(A10 = A11, NA(), COUNTIF($A$1:A9,"="&NA()) + COUNT ($A$1:A9) + 1 - SUMIF($A$1:A9,"<>#N/A"))
```

The code does work, but I really can't find the equivalent in SAS for COUNTIF, SUMIF, and COUNT....

Here is my code so far

```
data test;
input sign;
cards;
-1
1
1
0
-1
-1
;
run;

*create a lead for the equality IF
proc expand data=test out=test2;
convert sign= sign_lead / transformout = (lead 1);
quit;
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take advantage of FIRST and LAST automatic variables.  They're created when you use BY.  I use NOTSORTED here since you don't actually want to change the order for all the -1s to be together (as that would defeat the purpose).  This is something well covered in various papers if you google "FIRST LAST Variable SAS".

```
data test;
input sign;
cards;
-1
1
1
0
-1
-1
;
run;

data want;
set test;
by sign notsorted;
if first.sign then _tempcounter=0;
_tempcounter+1;
if last.sign then b=_tempcounter;
drop _tempcounter;
run;
proc print data=want;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks!
Working perfectly, and now I understand better how to use SAS